# loading a webpage into a div-not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a webpage into a div...But It's not getting loaded into the div...instead it's loading as a whole webpage....why??

```
<li><a href="#" onClick="AboutUs();">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
<div class="bdy"></div>
```

javascript code:

```
function AboutUs () {
    // body...
//$('.bdy').load('http://www.jhsoftech.com' );
$('.bdy').html('<object style="width:100%;height:435px;" data="http://www.erail.in">');
}
```

Comment: `<div class="bdy">` is right. You don't need the dot

Comment: yea...I was in a bit hurry while posting the question..

Comment: I think you can't do that. check this [**Link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain).

Comment: `if(top!=self)top.location.href="http://erail.in";` This is why it's redirecting.. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JKZ2h/

Comment: thank you...kilian Stinson and Jai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened your site in an iframe sandbox.

[**JSFIDDLE Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKZ2h/)

```
$('.bdy').html('<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" style="width:100%;height:435px;" src="http://www.erail.in"><iframe>');
})
```

The problem with your site, setting another location / redirecting the page is this part of code on the your site:

```
if(top!=self)top.location.href="http://erail.in";
```

Remove this and you are able to implement it without a sandbox preventing `allow-top-navigation`.

Comment: thank you...Kilian Stinson...but if the link is www.erail.in/?R=12622.
What to do..Here, First page loads and then the content loads dynamically If I directly give this link in your code...the content is not getting loaded i.e., the information of the train no.12622..what to do??

Comment: Try adding `allow-same-origin` to the `sandbox` attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/JKZ2h/1/

Comment: thank you...Kilian stinson It works...fine..
If I had to do with load function..can you tell me...how to do that..?? I am asking because if I can do it with load...I can display only the table I wanted to display...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ is limited to the same domain/subdomain, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change  to

```
<div class="bdy"></div>
```

And use jquery take a look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/TEHsJ/

Comment: instead of using .html use your commented .load

Comment: You just cant see it works in Jsfiddle since they wont allow it.

Comment: If I use that .load it shows...access denied allow origin..some error..same origin policy..so i just used .html it works fine..